# Symfony2 JSON Object - Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '636'

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, symfony

I'm trying to loop through the content of a JSON data object which is returned by an action in Symfony2.
Whether i use the *$.getJSON* or *$.ajax* is still get the dame error being thrown :**"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '636'"**
Below  the AJAX request and a the data returned:  `

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a.parents ').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var newRow = '<table>\n\
<thead>\n\
<tr>\n\
<th>Nom</th>\n\
<th>Prenom(s)</th>\n\\n\
</tr>\n\
</thead>\n\
';
$.getJSON(Routing.generate($(this).attr('data-href'),{id: $(this).attr('data-id')}),
function(data) {
$.each(data.parents, function (i, parent) {
    newRow += '<tr><td>' + parent[i].nom + '</td><td>' + parent[i].prenoms + '</td></tr>';
});
newRow += '</table>';
alert(newRow);
},
'json'); 
});
});
`
```

The sample result returned by the Action:
`{"success":true,"parents":"{\u0022nom\u0022:\u0022Dafn\\u00e9e\u0022,\u0022prenoms\u0022:\u0022Graham\u0022},{\u0022nom\u0022:\u0022G\\u00e9raldine\u0022,\u0022prenoms\u0022:\u0022Phillips\u0022},{\u0022nom\u0022:\u0022H\\u00e9l\\u00e8na\u0022,\u0022prenoms\u0022:\u0022Hernandez\u0022},{\u0022nom\u0022:\u0022Ma\\u00eblla\u0022,\u0022prenoms\u0022:\u0022Perez\u0022},{\u0022nom\u0022:\u0022Illustr\\u00e9e\u0022,\u0022prenoms\u0022:\u0022Dixon\u0022},{\u0022nom\u0022:\u0022Ru\\u00ec\u0022,\u0022prenoms\u0022:\u0022Griffin\u0022},{\u0022nom\u0022:\u0022Rach\\u00e8le\u0022,\u0022prenoms\u0022:\u0022Kennedy\u0022},{\u0022nom\u0022:\u0022B\\u00e9n\\u00e9dicte\u0022,\u0022prenoms\u0022:\u0022Ferguson\u0022},{\u0022nom\u0022:\u0022Gis\\u00e8le\u0022,\u0022prenoms\u0022:\u0022Myers\u0022},{\u0022nom\u0022:\u0022Laur\\u00e9lie\u0022,\u0022prenoms\u0022:\u0022Mason\u0022},{\u0022nom\u0022:\u0022Y\\u00e9nora\u0022,\u0022prenoms\u0022:\u0022Olson\u0022},{\u0022nom\u0022:\u0022L\\u00e9onie\u0022,\u0022prenoms\u0022:\u0022Burns\u0022},{\u0022nom\u0022:\u0022Bj\\u00f6rn\u0022,\u0022prenoms\u0022:\u0022Vasquez\u0022},{\u0022nom\u0022:\u0022M\\u00e9lia\u0022,\u0022prenoms\u0022:\u0022Butler\u0022},{\u0022nom\u0022:\u0022R\\u00e1o\u0022,\u0022prenoms\u0022:\u0022Armstrong\u0022}]"}`
i'm using the [JMS Serializer Bundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle)  in my action as below:

```
public function trainingCandidatesAction(Request $request,$id) {
        $request = $this->get('request');
    try{
     if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() || $request->getMethod() == 'GET' || $request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $array = $em->getRepository('ParentsBundle:Parents')->getParentsByFormation($id);

            $serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');
            $jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($array,'json');
            }

            return new JsonResponse(array('success'=>true, 'parents'=>$jsonContent));
    }catch(\Execption $exception)
    {
         return new JsonResponse(array(
            'success' => false,
            'code'    => $exception->getCode(),
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
        ));
    }

        }
```

I've been through the various suggested approached from similar questions on stackoverflow but wasn't able to get it right, i must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to get a clean JSON, you need to decode your data before render a `JsonResponse`:

```
return new JsonResponse(array(
    'success'=>true, 
    'parents'=> json_decode($jsonContent),
);
```

That's because your data are already serialised, and the `JsonResponse` encode them once again.

Then, if that doesn't fix your error, try to parse the json before use it, e.g. :

```
$.each(JSON.parse(data.parents), function(i, parent) {
    // ...  
});
```

Hope this helps you.